# If I save some information with PlayerPrefs, they will remain saved even if the game is online?

Tags: unity, savegame

If I make a game in unity and I use the PlayerPrefs function to save the progress and load it in another play, that information will be stored even if the game is loaded on an online platform? I mean: I save a number: 4. Then i close the web page, and enter again and hit load. That number will be saved and loaded properly for every user that plays the game?

Comment: i am new here, how can I do that?

Comment: oh, nvm, I did it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I did some googling and according to another question it should work online with one exception :

> Basically there are no hard limits, with exception of WebPlayer, which is limited to a 1 MB.

And if this were to happen, it will throw a [PlayerprefException](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefsException.html).

---

Source : http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/182755/playerprefs-lmitations.html